# Merging PDF's with special characters in file name with Sejda Console via .CSV

Tags: csv, batch-file, pdf, sejda

I'm new to this forum and I'm not a programmer, so forgive me if I'm asking stupid questions...
I'm trying to merge some pdf's to 1 pdf with [Sejda Console](http://sejda.org/) using a .csv file, but when the .csv contains special characters (e.g. `ø`) Sejda returns with:

> Invalid filename found: File 'Something **ï¿½** something.pdf"...

So, it changed `ø` in `ï¿½`.

I've tried to import the .csv with different encoding standards (via Notepad save as: ANSI, UNICODE and UTF-8) and they all don't work (but, they have all a unique way to screw up the filename...)
Without this kind of characters it works fine.
It also works fine when the file names with ø are given directly in the syntax, like:
`sejda-console-3.1.3/bin/sejda-console merge -f first.pdf second.pdf -o merged.pdf`

And a second problem occurred: when a comma exists in the file name, the file name stops by the comma. Logically when the list separator is still a comma, but on my pc the list separator is a semicolon (Regional and Language Options). Adding quotes around the file name doesn't work...

I call the batch of Sejda with:

```
call "C:\sejda-console-3.0.13\bin\sejda-console.bat" merge -l 28.csv -o 28.pdf
```

And for this test 28.csv contains:

```
1700050.1_0060764-CROSS TRACK SKATE AXLE.pdf,
1700050.1_0060792-ø32 ATK10K6 FIXING PLATE.pdf,
1700050.1_0060798-CROSS TRACK SKATE NUTPLATE.pdf,
```

What is the proper way to get Sejda to merge correctly?